# How to update DOM when value changes in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model, ng-bind

I have a function getData which just increments value of var counter.

Whenever an increment takes place, I want angular to automatically update that inside a div

I've tried ng-bind but it only works if I click on a form element.

```
enquire.controller('DisplayEnquiries', function($scope){
$scope.getData = function(){
    console.log('Run ' + $scope.counter);
    $scope.counter;
    if($scope.counter == undefined || $scope.counter == null){
        $scope.counter = 1
        $scope.counter++;
    }
    else{
        $scope.counter++;
    }
    console.log('Execute ' + $scope.counter);
    $scope.count = $scope.counter;
}
    setInterval($scope.getData, 1000);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-5" ng-controller="DisplayEnquiries">
        <h4>Unread User Queries</h4>
        <p>
            Count : <span ng-bind="count"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular do have digest system which helps to provided updated binding over the view. But When you updated angular bindings from outer world of angular like `any (async) event`, angular doesn't understand the change, resultant digest cycle won't get fire to updated binding. So in your case you are running `setInterval`(async event) which is updating binding.

In such scenario you need to manually kick of digest cycle (`$scope.$apply()`/`$scope.$digest()`) to look for change and update binding accordingly over the view. But still I'd prefer you to use `$interval` service which is provided out of the box which does same work as `setInterval` & that does take care of digest cycle to keep binding in sync.

You should use `$interval` instead of `setInterval`

```
$interval($scope.getData, 1000);
```